# Mapping google maps coordinate from a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variables, coordinates

I can successfully generate a google map with the code below:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.77493, -122.419415);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

However when I try to do it with the block of code below (storing the coordinate in a variable). The map comes up as all blue, with or with out the replace function.

```
var coordinate = "37.77493,-122.419415";
coordinate = coordinate.replace('"','');
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The google.maps.LatLng constructor takes two numbers (like your first example), not a string (like the code that doesn't work).  Where do those two numbers come from?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/water_ca_gov_GeoRectifyA.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [`LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) constructor takes two numbers not a string

```
var coordinates = "37.77493,-122.419415".split(',');
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);
```

Comment: I edited code and solution is same with you :) Is this a joke :)