# google maps dynamic coordinates with jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dynamic-programming

I am trying to get my map canvas to populate its location dynamically based on the address the customer clicks on in their profile. The var address is returning correctly but the var coords is returning as (NaN, NaN).  If I take the coordinates in the address variable and manually enter them in the LatLng function, the map generates just fine.  For some reason I cannot get it to work with using a variable though, the map is just gray.  Any advice or help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
$( ".address_string" ).click(function(event) {      
    var address = this.getAttribute('data-coords');
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(address);

    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    center: coords
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions); 
});
```

For example, if I were to run the code below with the coordinates manually entered it would work just fine.  The coords I am using in this example is copied directly from the data-coords attribute that this snippet pulls from on one of the addresses and are exactly what displays if i run alert(address);.

```
$( ".address_string" ).click(function(event) {      
    var address = this.getAttribute('data-coords');
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(33.5385599, -112.095828);

    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    center: coords
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491113/mapping-google-maps-coordinate-from-a-javascript-variable).  I have been searching for 2 days and couldn't figure this out and kept delaying on asking my question just knowing I was just about to find it.  Sure enough, 20 minutes after I post I find it.....